# How can I find this elliptic integral?

Tags: integration

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}$$

After trying to do it for a while I posted it on Wolfram Alpha but I get no solution. How do I do it?

Comment: It's an elliptic integral, not for the faint of heart. In particular, it has no solution in so-called elementary functions.

Comment: FYI, you don't $\textit{find}$ the integral, you $\textit{solve}$ it)

Comment: @Alex Well, you *find a primitive*, or *find an antiderivative*. You *solve* a problem, but not an integral, really.

Comment: Yeah, in my textbook it says find.

Answer (score 1):

Maple gives this answer:
$${\frac {\sqrt {1-i{x}^{2}}\sqrt {1+i{x}^{2}}{\it EllipticF} \left( x
 \left( 1/2\,\sqrt {2}+1/2\,i\sqrt {2} \right) ,i \right) }{ \left( 1/
2\,\sqrt {2}+1/2\,i\sqrt {2} \right) \sqrt {1+{x}^{4}}}}
$$

Comment: Mathematica's answer is more compact: $-(-1)^{1/4}\text{EllipticF}\left(i \sinh^{-1}\left((-1)^{1/4}x\right),-1\right)$

Comment: @Ruslan: Fascinating that these two answers can be the same. Clearly, EllipticF is a somewhat nontrivial beast.